# ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction - Oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I am using ADOdb Library for a PHP application.

This application works smoothly with Oracle 9g, but when we transferred it to a new server it often throws the following error:

> ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

Is it maybe a problem with oci_8.dll I am using? Should I update it to php_oci8_11g.dll?

Comment: Despite that good answer below I encourage updating the driver's dll to 11g when working with Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 6):

This error would occur if your isolation level was set to `serializable` and you were doing DML on tables that other were also doing DML on.

Are you setting such an isolation level + doing DML, and if so why isn't the standard `read committed` ok for you?

for example:

someone removes a row

```
ANOTHER SESSION                   YOUR SESSION

SQL> delete from a where id = 1;

1 row deleted.
```

commit not done yet..meanwhile, your SERIALIZED transaction tries to remove the same row...

```
SQL> alter session set isolation_level=serializable;

Session altered.

SQL> delete from a where id = 1;
```

your session will hang  at this point as the other session has the lock.
if that other session now commits:

```
SQL> commit;        

Commit complete.
```

your session hits that error:

```
delete from a where id = 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
```

Comment: Thanks DazzaL. Here is the thing: we indeed changed isolation level to READ COMMITTED. However, when we decided to test its efficiency by issuing an invoice for the same customer at the same time, we got the same invoice being issued twice with the same invoice number, as the numbering of the invoice is generated by fetching the MAX invoice number at that time. So, by running the same procedure in two different machines the MAX invoice number returned to both, was the same number!

Comment: Anyway, the thing is that this piece of code was running smoothly in 9g with SERIALIZABLE and now in 11g it does not. So, does this probably mean that 9g was set in SERILIZABLE mode?